# Is it possible to exclude certain columns when copying an entire row in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I am currently copying a certain rows depending if they contain a certain value. However, I actually only want to copy some of the columns rather then the entire row. What is the simplest way of doing this? MY current code:

```
Sub output()

Dim i, Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Sheets("Dec").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Looping from tenth row to last row

For i = 7 To Lastrow

If Sheets("Dec").Cells(i, "AQ").Value = "Shortage" Or Sheets("Dec").Cells(i, "AQ").Value = "Customer" Then
    Sheets("Dec").Cells(i, "AQ").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Action").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)


End If
Next i

Sheets("Action").Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: Short answer is No. You will have to either specify columns or delete afterwards.

Comment: Note that `Dim i, Lastrow As Long` will declare `Lastrow As Long` but `i As Variant`. You must specify a type for **every** variable in VBA: `Dim i As Long, Lastrow As Long` otherwise it is `Variant` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Union function to unions at least two ranges or cells
[image]

```
Private Const column1 As String = "A"
Private Const column3 As String = "C"
Private Const column5 As String = "E"
Private Const column7 As String = "G"

Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim unionRange As Range
    Dim rangeSelection As String

    i = 1
    rangeSelection = column5 & i & ":" & column7 & i


    Set unionRange = Union(Cells(i, column1), Cells(i, column3), Range(rangeSelection))
    unionRange.Select
    unionRange.Copy

    Range(column1 & "2").PasteSpecial    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Imagine the following data:

[image]

If you want to copy columns A, B, C and G, H, I you can do that eg with `Range("A1:C1,G1:I1").Copy`. If you then paste it into A3 using `Range("A3").Paste` you will end up with

[image]

But if you expected it to paste with columns D, E, F being empty like below

[image]

Then you must copy and past each range one after the other (you cannot do it in one step)

```
Range("A1:C1").Copy
Range("A3").Paste

Range("G1:I1").Copy
Range("G3").Paste
```

Alternatively of course you can copy the whole row and clear columns D, E, F.

Comment: Perfect thanks! Using my old code `Sheets("Dec").Cells(i, "AQ").EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Action").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)`
 , can I only paste value with number formats

Comment: OKay, last question. How would I include my loop (i) in the range.pastSpecial method?

Comment: @PhilipOlsson that is a different question actually. Show in your question what you have tried and what went wrong, otherwise it is just asking us to do the work for you.